# Is it possible to simulate a facebook tracking pixel request server side?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I'm working with Rails 3.2 and I'm trying to set up a tracking pixel at the end of a website's signup process.

The issue I have though is that the signup process is done via js/ajax and once they complete it, I send a user to one of a few different pages. ie some get A, some get B, some get C.

I don't want to put the same pixel on all 3 because I may change the pages or swap them out in the future.

So is it possible to simulate the same request that the facebook tracking pixel makes but server side?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a conversion pixel for Facebook you get a code snippet you can add to your html. This code snippet it's just a javascript code that fires the pixel. If you debug the page you'll see that the only thing it does is a GET call to a URL. You can copy that URL and make a cURL call (GET) from your server any time you want.

This is an example of the URL:

https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=null&ev=CONVERSION_PIXEL_ID&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fmyurl.com%2F&rl=&if=false&cd[value]=0.01&cd[currency]=USD

However, I do not recommend to do this. It's better if you leave Facebook building the URL and firing it through the javascript snippet. This is not reliable and your data might be alterated. If you do not use the code snippet you won't be able to complain to Facebook if your data doesn't match as you're not following the standard process.

What I really recommend is create a different pixel id for each page.

I hope it makes sense.
Javier.

Comment: Thanks for answering @javier. I was doing just that(more or less) with mixed results which is why I asked to see if anyone else has tried/figured out how to do it more successfully.

Comment: That won't work server-side. When it's fired by a browser, it includes meta information (like user agent), and also cookies and more. It's for tracking the user, so the context of the user needs to be trackable. The URL may change, but the data being send to track the user would be more changable. I think it's near impossible to read the pixel cookie data (their domain) from your own domain to send to your server.